# Trying to create a relationships between nodes with 2 different properties names but some of them have the same value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hey all a beginner neo4j student here o/
I created 40 nodes
`20 :EMPLOYEE and 20 :ORGANIZATION` nodes

Employee nodes have the `owns_organizationNr` property

Organization nodes have the ownedBy_organizationNr property

some  of those nodes have the same value and I tried the query below
to create relationships between those who match by the property value and insert the
`n1.owns_organizationNr` property and value into to new relationship but something is missing
can you guys help me, please?

```
MATCH (n1:EMPLOYEE) , (n2:ORGANIZATION) 
WHERE
  HAS(n1.owns_organizationNr) AND HAS(n2.ownedBy_organizationNr) AND n1.owns_organizationNr = n2.ownedBy_organizationNr
CREATE (n1) -[:OWNS_ORG{n1.owns_organizationNr}]->(n2)
```

Comment: is there an error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is doing a cartesian product so it is resulting to a lot of rows. You can use below query. Also, there is a typo error on the CREATE statement. I also fix it in the last line.

```
MATCH (n1:EMPLOYEE) WHERE  n1.owns_organizationNr is not null
WITH n1
MATCH (n2:ORGANIZATION) 
WHERE n2.ownedBy_organizationNr is not null AND n1.owns_organizationNr = n2.ownedBy_organizationNr 
CREATE (n1) -[:OWNS_ORG{owns_organizationNr: n1.owns_organizationNr}]->(n2)
```

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: I tried your query but sadly it said "(no changes, no records)"

Comment: It worked for me; can you run this query to check if the values n1.owns_organizationNr = n2.ownedBy_organizationNr are exactly the same?  MATCH (n1:EMPLOYEE) WHERE  n1.owns_organizationNr is not null WITH n1 MATCH (n2:ORGANIZATION) RETURN (n1.owns_organizationNr = n2.ownedBy_organizationNr) as check

Comment: Above debugging query should return some values to be true. If all values are false, then there is a problem on the data.